# Detect Jquery img src update in knockout Model

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

We need to update img src with Jquery but that change is not being detected in Knockout observable property.

Kindly Advice

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script(in my case I have use hover event.)

```
$(function() {
$("img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.gif";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over.gif", ".gif");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
```

});

Comment: It will update the img src in html correctly we are also able to update it, but we have to bind this image to knokuout Viewmodel. Updateing src attr via Jquery/Javascrit not updating MVVM property.

Comment: Create a custom binding, that bridges between the observable and jQuery. But why not update the src with KO only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Firstly add this event in your databind in your html :

  <input class=" input-file" id="fileUpload" type="file" data-bind="event: { change: _updateImg}" />
```

Next, create the function _updateImg in your js file, this function replace your img :

```
function _updateImg(data, event) {
        var me = this, files, reader;
        files = event.currentTarget.files;

        // Ajout de la photo après sélection
        if (files.length > 0) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                me.pictureUrl(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    };
```

Ask me if u want some informations ..